# Struct inside union

Tags: c, unions

I'm trying to build network application and I need to be able to write one choice at a time, one, two or three. The below union writes 4 chars to the network even if I used only struct one.

```
union choice_
{
    struct one_
    {
        unsigned char one[2];
    }src;   
    struct two_
    {
        unsigned char two[2];
    }two;
    struct three
    {
        unsigned char one[2];
        unsigned char two[2];
    }three;
}choice;
```

Can't I just write choice.one

I'm a bit confused here, how can I build a choice of structs?

Comment: This will probably be migrated to StackOverflow, so you might want to set up an account there.

Comment: While Lundin's answer is the right answer, in helping to understand the problem you're having I'd like to ask how exactly are you writing `choice.one` to the network.

Answer (score 4):

A union is as large as its largest member because it has to be able to store the largest member at any time. In this case, you've got `struct three` which contains two arrays of two characters each, for a total of four characters, so any instance of `choice` is going to be four characters long.

Answer (score 3):

The union does not help you at all, but rather obfuscates the code and increases the chance of insertion of unwanted padding bytes. Instead, do like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  char data[2];
} choice_t;

...

void write_bytes_to_network (const choice_t* choice);

...

choice_t one = ...;
choice_t two = ...;

switch(something)
{
  case 1: 
    write_bytes_to_network (&one);
    break;

  case 2:
    write_bytes_to_network (&two);
    break;

  case 3:
    write_bytes_to_network (&one);
    write_bytes_to_network (&two);
    break;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the only solution which ditches union, since that seems irrelevant to solving his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
union choice_ u;
...
write(<fd>, u.one, sizeof(u.one));
```

or if it's two

```
union choice_ u;
...
write(<fd>, u.two, sizeof(u.two));
```

or in the third case

```
union choice_ u;
...
write(<fd>, u.three, sizeof(u.three));
```

Note however that in your case `sizeof(union choice_)` will always equal the size of `struct three`.